# I imported this dataset to RStudio but it is NULL

Tags: r

I am trying to study this dataset but whenever I use the str, head or summary functions it always comes back as NULL:

```
nhanes <- write.csv2("nhanes3.csv")

summary(nhanes)
str(nhanes)

 NULL
 NULL
```

Do you know anything that could help me get this fixed?

Answer (score 3):

`write.csv2` will take a dataframe you have in R and save it as a csv.  If you need to import a csv, you'll want to use `read.csv` or `read.csv2` depending on the format of your file.

Comment: I've tried `read.csv2()` and I get this `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : first five rows are empty: giving up`

Comment: Maybe try `read.csv`?  I assume it depends on how numbers are written where you are--whether . or , is used for decimals and what separator is used for the file.  I've only ever used `read.csv` (. decimal and , separator) myself.  `read.csv2` is for when your data uses ; as a separator and , for decimals, so if your data isn't in that format, it will likely return an error since it's probably not going to find the semi-colons its looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately got the same error back when I tried `read.csv()`

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is, but I've been more successful reading poorly formatted `.csv` files using `fread()` from the `data.table` package. It may also be useful to crack open the file and verify the format (single versus double quotes for characters, comma or tab deliminator, stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

If the first five rows are empty, you need to skip those rows.

If your data has a header

```
df <- read.csv("path to your data", header=T, skip=5)
```

If your data doesn't have a header

```
df <- read.csv("path to your data", header=F, skip=5)
```

Comment: The thing is, the first 5 rows aren't empty. I do't know why RStudio gives that error back.

Comment: if there is a way for you to share the dataset, it would help a lot.